# MySQL -PHP insert DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql, database

can anyone please guide me on How to insert a DATETIME filed from iphone through PHP script into MySQL database.

```
$dates = date('Y-m-d H:i:s','2010-10-12 15:09:00');

$query = "INSERT INTO timeTable(time) VALUES ('$dates')";
```

Thank you..

Comment: FYI Im sending the date from Iphone form to the php script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For `date()` function as a second argument you should pass a timestamp.

```
$dates =date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2010-10-12 15:09:00') );
```

But you have already your time in a good form sou you should just do:

```
$dates = '2010-10-12 15:09:00';
```

Comment: This is working but it doesnt insert data into my MySQL table. i cant seem to figure out the solution...thanks

Comment: Try to print your `$query` and paste into `phpMyAdmin` for example. Check if query has all your data, etc..

Comment: Thanks.$query is showing correct date,but not inserting date into mysql table where as database field datatype is DATETIME.